# eb config and .ebextensions/ - .ebextensions/ not working

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

It is my understanding that editing the config via `eb config` and via `.ebextensions/` both do the same thing. Using `eb config` directly changes the config were using `.ebextensions/` changes the config but is scripted, thus repeatable.

**Is this correct?**

Initially, I usesed `ebconf` to change

```
aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    NumProcesses: '1'
    NumThreads: '15'
    WSGIPath: application
```

to

```
aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    NumProcesses: '1'
    NumThreads: '15'
    WSGIPath: project.wsgi # <-- change
```

which worked and I was able to run my application.

I then decided I wanted to do all my changes thru `.ebextensions/`.  I reverted the change made with `eb config`  and created the file `.ebextensions/02_python.config` which contains:

```
option_settings:
   "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
     WSGIPath: project.wsgi
     NumProcesses: 3
     NumThreads: 20
   "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles":
     "/static/": "static/"
```

after `eb deploy`  all the chages are reflected when I do `eb config` except the **WSGIPath** value is not changed thus my app is no longer working.

Why is `.ebextensions/02_python.config`  not overwriting that one value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to fix this issue.

`eb config`

delete *WSGIPath: application*

save and wait for reload

`eb deploy`

save and wait for reload

`eb config`

verify the changes from the file are made!